# Variables Inside JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have created a Div Tag inside menu `li` and added a Class `Div1` to it.
Everything working good.
But Now I want to create div tags with `div1`, and on another click `div2` and then `div3`.

So is it possible to use variable and have a counter inside it?

```
     $(document).ready(function(){


            $(".menu a").click(function () {

       $("<div> Label </div>").appendTo(".menu li").addClass("div1");
                                 $(".div1").show(function () {
                           $(".div1").editInPlace({
                            url: "./server",
                            show_buttons: true
                                });//editinplace

                         });//show
                        });//click
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to change the class, but in case you do that's included... i don't see the ID getting set....

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var increment = 0;
    $(".menu a").click(function () 
    {
        increment++;
        $("<div> Label </div>").appendTo(".menu li").addClass("div" + increment);
        $(".div" + increment).show(function () 
        {
            $(".div" + increment).editInPlace({
                url: "./server",
                show_buttons: true
            });//editinplace

        });//show
    });//click
});
```

the scope chaining in javascript means that the 'increment' variable is always visible to the click function.

Comment: Hi,Its working Good..But if i used $("div"+increment).html(); to get the changed value..Its showing simply Label..But i needed the value what i have edited so that i can insert that value into my database.Suggest me please...

Comment: Hi,

Believe it or not, I've never used jquery. I guessed the above example based on your code and my knowledge of javascript.

You need to look up jquery and how to use that, maybe create another question for that part of the issue or update this question. I think I solved the original question as stated, however I would like to add this:

You should be identifying the divs by ID not class, take a look at the jquery documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to specify div1,div2 etc. I've used edit in place with jquery. I just add same class (like editable) to all the elements that I need to edit in place and put in ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".editable").editInPlace(...../*other stuff*/);
});
```

Comment: SInce i need to fetch values of separate div..Im creating like this.

Comment: @Aruna you can use $(this) to get html from the div that raised the event, that is the div that is clicked!